# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array in flutter google_maps_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

In my flutter application I am using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) for showing location,but I face this again and again when map loads lot of locations also it arise on zoom in/out action.

I already saw this issue on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/121813) but,unable to find solution their.

For more detail,below is error log:

FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 247496
Process: com.jio.jcpapps, PID: 31625
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at java.nio.ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.java:122)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414037@23.24.14 (150400-0):2)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414037@23.24.14 (150400-0):3)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.ai.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414037@23.24.14 (150400-0):30)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.ao.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414037@23.24.14 (150400-0):10)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bx.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414037@23.24.14 (150400-0):29)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bq.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414037@23.24.14 (150400-0):157)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.at.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414037@23.24.14 (150400-0):48)

---

**Edit** 1- after some R&D I found this issue is not getting on google_maps_flutter: 2.0.6 version,but problem is this also too old,not compatible with latest flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research i found a "solution" that worked perfectly for me. I don't think it's the best way of solving this, but it works fine and didn't crashed the app.

So, on the `MaterialPageRoute`/`CupertinoPageRoute` inside the `Navigator.of(context).push()` i set both `maintainState` and `modal` to true, so the screen was always kept in stack. This didn't affect the performance and also fixed the problem for me.

I hope this works for you as well.

Comment: The problem is not about navigation or routing, it's all about google_map plugin because this problem also arises even if you make a single-page app.